# Фреймворк yii2. При попытке зарегистрироваться выдаёт ошибку error 404

Tags: yii2

Пытаюсь учить фреймворк по чужому проекту. Фреймворк установил через композер, перенёс туда проект, через композер установил все зависимости, подправил config. Всё работает хорошо, но при попытке зарегистрироваться или войти в систему выдаёт ошибку 404. Сам файл register.php существует и роуты прописаны хорошо. Скажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

Вот ссылка на проект: https://github.com/Nikita-C47/gb. Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: Добрый вечер. А чёрт его знает, гадалки в отпуске... Как можно что-то решить не видя кода, не зная структуры? Вы так можете?

Comment: Вероятно в процессе входа запрашивается ресурс отсутствующий на сервере. Быть может, где-то в скрипте прописан редирект на какой-нибудь домен отличный от вашего. Или... *а дальше неразборчиво*

Comment: ну где у Вас прописаны роуты не видно.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо немного изменить ссылки в layouts/main.php. Надо убрать слеш и обернуть маршрут в квадратные скобки.

Тогда будет всё работать. Но при этом будет сохранена "web" в адресе. Это решается другим путём, чем настройка маршрутов.

```
    echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'Добавить запись', 'url' => ['main/add-entry']],
        Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? (
            [
                'label' => 'Войти/Зарегистрироваться',
                'items' => [
                    ['label' => 'Войти', 'url' => ['main/login']],
                    ['label' => 'Зарегистрироваться', 'url' => ['main/register']]
                ]
            ]
        ) : ([
            'label' => Yii::$app->user->identity->name,
            'items' => [
                ['label' => 'Мои записи', 'url' => ['main/my-entries']],
                ['label' => 'Настройки', 'url' => ['main/settings']],
                '<li class="divider"></li>',
                '<li>' . Html::a('Выйти', ['main/logout'],
                    [
                        'title' => 'Выйти',
                        'data' => ['method' => 'post']
                    ])
                .'</li>',
            ]
        ])
    ],
]);
```

Подробней читайте в документации.

[на русском](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/docs/guide-ru)

[на русском, но чуть лучше оформлена](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru)

[на буржуйском](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0)

[отличный блог и не только по yii2](https://elisdn.ru/blog/tag/Yii2)

p.s. Необходимо обновить проект до последней версии yii2

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Но всё равно при попытке зарегистрироваться выдаёт ошибку 404

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо